# [Cocoa][OpenGL2.7] How to get app focus?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to MacOs. Trying to move my game to macos from windows but don't know anything about it.
How can I get my app is focused or not using CocoaAPI or OpenGL 2.7 API?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That code works!

if (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_ACTIVE) != GL_TRUE)